# Reversible streaming hash function

Tags: hash, cryptography, hashing, streaming-algorithm

Do any streaming hash functions exist that provide the same result if the input is reversed?

That is to say, is there some hash function, $h$, such that:

$$ h(h(h(h(0, x_1), x_2), ...), x_n) = h(h(h(h(0, x_n), ...), x_2), x_1) $$

If this is impossible, why is it impossible?

I am interested in sending packets of constant size around a circuit in a network in both directions, having each node add its value to the hash and then, when the packets meet, compare the hash values.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, not a dup, because that question does not contain the requirement to be able to compute it in a streaming fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, the problem is impossible (with a non-trivial hash function). Consider the case n=2, then you have that, for example,

$$h(h(0, 1), 2) = h(h(0, 2), 1)$$

That implies that

$$h(h(h(0, 1), 2), 3) = h(h(h(0, 2), 1), 3)$$

So the strings $1,2,3$ and $2,1,3$ are forced to have the same hash even if one is not the reverse of the other. A similar argument shows that any such hash function is not only reversal-independent, but in general permutation-independent, so it is equivalent to storing the multiset of characters of the input.

An alternative is to have a normal streaming hash function $h$ which is not reversal-independent, and then have a function $r$ that identifies the hashes of a string and its reverse. So the condition would become something like

$$ r(ℎ(ℎ(ℎ(ℎ(0,_1),_2),...),_))=r(ℎ(ℎ(ℎ(ℎ(0,_),...),_2),_1)) $$

And that is certainly possible with a reasonably strong hash function, as show by D.W.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm struggling to understand how the last part would be possible in practice.  Is $r$ basically a rainbow table?  I.e. it involves knowing all the possible inputs to the hash function?

Comment: D.W. provided an excellent example. The function h would return the pair (H(m), H(rev(m))) and then r(H(m), H(rev(m)) would just be the xor of both elements of the pair, therefore "forgetting" about the order.

Answer (score 3):

There are several polynomial-based hash functions $H$, where you can rapidly compute $H(m)$ or $H(\text{rev}(m))$ given $m$, and you can do both in a streaming fashion.  See below for several candidates for $H$.  Then, you can use

$$H'(m) = H(m) \oplus H(\text{rev}(m)),$$

and $H'$ will have the property you are looking for.

## Rabin hash

For instance, consider the [Rabin hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint).  Specifically, given a $n$-bit message $m=(m_0,\dots,m_{n-1})$, the hash is

$$H(m) = m_0 + m_1 x + \dots + m_{n-1} x^{n-1} \bmod p(x),$$

where $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$ over $GF(2)$.  This is easy to compute in a streaming fashion via the recurrence

$$w_i = x w_{i-1} \bmod p(x), \qquad h_i = h_{i-1} + m_i w_i \bmod p(x).$$

Now $\text{rev}(m)=(m_{n-1},\dots,m_1,m_0)$, so

$$H(\text{rev}(x)) = m_{n-1} + m_{n-2} x + \dots + m_0 x^{n-1} \bmod p(x),$$

which can be computed in a streaming fashion with the recurrence

$$h_i = x h_{i-1} + m_i \bmod p(x).$$

## Polynomial hash over the integers

A related scheme is to use the integers modulo $p$ (a prime). instead of the polynomials over $GF(2)$ modulo $p(x)$.  Specifically, given a $n$-bit message $m=(m_0,\dots,m_{n-1})$, the hash is

$$H(m) = m_0 + m_1 a + \dots + m_{n-1} a^{n-1} \bmod p,$$

where $p$ is a prime number and $1<a<p$.  This too can be computed in a streaming fashion, both for the message and for the reverse of the message, in the same manner as above.  This can be made more efficient by breaking $m$ down into $n$ chunks, with each chunk of $c$ bits, such that $2^n<p$, and let $m_i$ be the $i$th chunk of $m$.  For instance, each chunk might represent a byte or character of $m$.

Note that if you use chunks larger than a bit, then this assumes reversal means not "reversal as a bit-string" but "reversal as a sequence of characters".  If you want one notion of reversal, but a different granularity for computing the hash, this can be arranged by with a little bit of additional arithmetic, but it's probably not worth the bother to work out the equations.

## Buzhash

Another choice for $H$ is [Buzhash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#Cyclic_polynomial).  Let $h$ be some hash function that maps from characters to $k$-bit values.  Define $\oplus$ to represent xor, and $a \lll b$ to represent circular left-rotate of $a$ by $b$ bit positions (I will assume that $b$ is implicitly taken modulo $l$).  Given a $n$-character message $m=(m_0,\dots,m_{n-1})$, Buzhash is defined as

$$H(m) = (h(m_0) \lll n-1) \oplus (h(m_1) \lll n-2) \oplus \cdots \oplus (h(m_{n-2}) \lll 1) \oplus m_{n-1}.$$

This can be easily computed in a streaming fashion by

$$h_i = (h_{i-1} \lll 1) \oplus h(m_i).$$

Also $H(\text{rev}(m))$ can be easily computed in a streaming fashion by

$$h_i = h_{i-1} \oplus (m_i \lll i).$$

The same comments apply about the granularity of chunks.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer!  Apologies if my question was still not clear.

Comment: This is the answer!